# Stratus (RTMFP) simple interaction user-user example

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, p2p, rtmfp

do anyone know a link or example that shows how to communicate two users using Stratus?, I know that Adobe site has some examples.. but they are all related to video streaming and so..

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see the code but I  think it's  what you're looking for
[link text](http://code.google.com/p/as3p2p/)

code.google.com/p/pokerroulette/

code.google.com/p/projectstratosphere/

Comment: Yes, I can download the code via SVN, thx for the link, I'll try it out.

But, AFAIK, that's not a realtime multiplayer game.